# scanning multiple serial data bits reliably - 8051

Tags: serial-port, bit, uart, sampling, 8051

My hardware currently has four sets of sensors that I treat as four separate serial ports with receive functionality only enabled wired to the lower 4 bits of port 0. I have attempted numerous times to retrieve the correct serial port data (by aiming the lazer direct at the sensor) without success. I then researched that for more reliability, on a standard UART, each bit is sampled at 16x a second (I found this 3/4 down the page on https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/back-to-basics-the-universal-asynchronous-receiver-transmitter-uart/).

So I ended up rolling off my own version of that but due to my timings, my count is more like 32x a second, but that's ok.

I'm going to explain what I did first so everyone understands what is going on.

**code explanation**

I have four consecutive address locations setup to point to values of counters for each bit. Four bits are read simultaneously from hardware and a counter for that bit goes up or down based on whether that bit is set (light detected on that group of sensors) or clear (light not detected). This loop executes frequently at about a 9600bps speed.

The second loop only executes when a value is needed. This happens once every 16 times that the last loop executes (more like at a 600bps speed). It takes the counter value of each bit as if it was a signed number and uses the MSB value as the final value of that bit. Those MSB values get crammed together to form the official bit read from the sensors.

Is this approach OK to reliably determine whether the bit value is set or cleared?

And could I somehow redo this code so the processes run faster? because each loop consumes a large number of clock cycles (32 to 40) and if I can get it down to maybe 20 clock cycles, I'd be happy.

Also, this code is executed on AT89S52 microcontroller so I'm using its extended memory addresses.

**the code**

```
;memory is preinitialized to nulls
LAZMAJ equ 0E0h ;majority counters start address (end address at 0E4h)
MAJT equ 20h    ;Majority value at bit address

mov A,P0        ;get bit values from hardware
mov R1,#LAZMAJ  ;go to start of pointer

;loop uses 40 clock cycles out of 192 available
countmaj:
  rrc A         ;get bit
  jnc noincmaj
    inc @R1     ;bit is set so add 1 to counter for that bit
  noincmaj:
  jc incmaj
    dec @R1     ;bit is clear so subtract 1 from counter for that bit
  incmaj:
  inc R1        ;move pointer to next bit
cjne R1,#LAZMAJ+4,countmaj    ;see if pointer is out of range
;it is so end loop


;loop uses about 32 clock cycles and executes when we want data

mov R1,#LAZMAJ+4 ;go to out of range position
chkmaj:
    dec R1              ;decrement pointer first so we are within range
    mov MAJT,@R1        ;load value to majority variable. treat it as signed
    mov @R1,#0h         ;clear value from memory space
    mov C,MAJT.7        ;Take sign and use that as carry
    rlc A               ;and put it into our final variable
cjne R1,#LAZMAJ,chkmaj  ;if pointer isn't in first address then keep going
;otherwise exit loop and A=value we want
```

Comment: Your code doesn’t show that the p0.0-3 are treated as independent serial ports - do you really mean that each port pin p0.0-3 has a start-8bits-stop sequence going on? To speed up the per-bit loop, unroll it to four sets of jumping on the port bit value.

Comment: You can probably get away with 3x or 4x oversampling as long as you can be sure the sending end is actually pretty precise 600baud.

Comment: *"on a standard UART, each bit is sampled at 16x a second "* -- No, the sampling is performed at 16 (or 8) times the baud rate.

Comment: I think the point of the 16x “oversampling” is not in some way to average the signal, but actually to synchronised with the leading edge of the start bit and then sample 24 clocks later (i.e. the centre) for the first data bit then successive samples 16 clocks later. As long as the sender is at pretty much the exact baud rate, you don’t have to sample at such a high rate to achieve a reasonable result - 4x might be easier: as soon as the leading edge of the start bit is detected take the subsequent samples 6 clock cycles later then every 4 clocks after that. I’ve done 3x on an 8038.

Comment: It turns out the best solution for me was to have the bits always scanned at the same speed regardless of whatever else is going on in the system then when the full byte comes in, I have to immediately copy it to another variable so the program can use the data. I cannot freeze the scanning process at all or incorrect data will come in.

Comment: @Mike Since you found your own answer, it would be best to post it as an answer rather than a comment, This allows you to give more detail and help others with the same or similar questions. It also give you credit for figuring your problem out.